# “Problems during Electron packaging

Tags: javascript

When I'm writing code using Electron, this piece of code can run before packaging, but after packaging, this code can only return false, even though my ovpn-dco.inf has been installed.

```
export function checkOvpnDcoEnabled(): boolean {
  try {
    let exePath = join(ENGINE_DIR, './ovpn-dco-amd64/win10/pnputil.exe');
    const output = execSync(`${exePath} /enum-drivers | findstr -c:"ovpn-dco.inf"`).toString();
    if (output.toString().includes('ovpn-dco.inf')) {
      console.log(typeof(output))
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return false;
  }
}
```

Meanwhile, this piece of code has always been able to run.

```
export function installOvpnDcoDriver() {
  const platform = os.platform();
  const arch = os.arch();
  const release = os.release();


  if (platform !== 'win32') {
    console.error('This script only works on Windows.');
    process.exit(1);
  }


  let driverPath = '';
  let exePath = join(ENGINE_DIR, './ovpn-dco-amd64/win10/pnputil.exe');
  if (arch === 'x64') {
    driverPath = path.join(ENGINE_DIR, './ovpn-dco-amd64');
  } else if (arch === 'arm64') {
    driverPath = path.join(ENGINE_DIR, './ovpn-dco-arm64');
  } else {
    driverPath = path.join(ENGINE_DIR, './ovpn-dco-x86');
  }

  if (release.startsWith('10.')) {
    driverPath = path.join(driverPath, 'win10','ovpn-dco.inf');
  } else {
    driverPath = path.join(driverPath, 'win11','ovpn-dco.inf');
  }

  const ovpnDcoInstaller = spawn(`${exePath}`, ['-i', '-a',`${driverPath}`,'-f']);
  // const ovpnDcoInstaller = spawn('pnputil',['/add-driver', '${driverPath}','/install'] )


  ovpnDcoInstaller.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('err: ' + data.toString());
  });

  ovpnDcoInstaller.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString());
  });

  ovpnDcoInstaller.on('close', () => {
    mainWin?.webContents.send('install-ovpn-dco-end', checkOvpnDcoEnabled());
  });
}
```

This piece of code was written for the Windows operating system.

I’ve tried many methods, but the exe file after packaging cannot detect the existence of the driver.